# Boost Unit Testing a move constructor?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have this code here:

```
template <typename T>
sorted_vector<T>& sorted_vector<T>::operator = ( sorted_vector<T> && src ) {
    delete [] beg_;

beg_ = src.beg_;
end_ = src.end_;
cap_ = src.cap_;

src.beg_ = nullptr;
src.end_ = nullptr;
src.cap_ = nullptr;

return *this;
}
```

If I am trying to unit test this using the boost library, how can I compare the original location of the vector, and the new "moved to" location?

Comment: You mean besides reading the `beg_` member?

Comment: @RobKennedy I have to unit test it from another source file that does #include it, so if I am able to do that I am not sure how to go about it.